How to count the total entries by group when they are comma-separated
I'm working with the League of Legends Champions dataset



name
tags




Aatrox
Fighter


Ahri
Mage,Assassin


Akali
Assassin


Akshan
Marksman,Assassin


Alistar
Tank,Support



And I was wondering how to count the total champions per tag, I'm really new in R, so I made a solution that I think is very bad and I know that may be a function that can help with this.
Here are the packages that I'm using
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

First, I separate my tags in different columns
lol_champions_tags <- lol_champions_clean %>% 
  select(name, tags) %>% 
  separate(tags, sep = ',', into = paste0('tag', 1:2))

Then, I calculate the total entries per tag
lol_champions_tags %>% 
  select(name, tag1) %>% 
  group_by(tag1) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) -> tag1

lol_champions_tags %>% 
  select(name, tag2) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  group_by(tag2) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) -> tag2

And finally I put all together and made the addition
champions_per_tag <-
bind_cols(tag1, tag2) %>%
clean_names() %>%
select(tag1,n_2,n_4) %>%
mutate(total_entries = n_2 + n_4) %>%
select(tag1, total_entries)

I was wondering if there was better way to do this or if there is a function that could handle this type of situation.

Please correct your last code section and display desired output.

Maybe you want just this one-liner
> as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(lol_champs$tags, ",", fixed=TRUE))))
      Var1 Freq
1 Assassin    3
2  Fighter    1
3     Mage    1
4 Marksman    1
5  Support    1
6     Tank    1


The last code section appears unclear to, so I do not replicate it.

Note
lol_champs = read.table(text="name   tags
Aatrox  Fighter
Ahri    Mage,Assassin
Akali   Assassin
Akshan  Marksman,Assassin
Alistar     Tank,Support", header=TRUE)


Why not just separate longer with a delim, and then count?
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

lol_champs |>
    separate_longer_delim(cols = tags, delim = ",") |>
    count(tags)

      tags n
1 Assassin 3
2  Fighter 1
3     Mage 1
4 Marksman 1
5  Support 1
6     Tank 1


You can do this quite easily with tidyverse functions. Use stringr::str_split to split the tags column into a list of separated words, then unnest and count...
lol_champs %>% mutate(tags = str_split(tags, ",")) %>% 
   unnest_longer(tags) %>% 
   count(tags)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  tags         n
  <chr>    <int>
1 Assassin     3
2 Fighter      1
3 Mage         1
4 Marksman     1
5 Support      1
6 Tank         1


separate_longer_delim?

A tidyverse one-liner:
# PKGs (dplyr, tidyr) -----------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data ----------------------------------------------------------------
lol_data <- tibble::tribble(
      ~name,               ~tags,
   "Aatrox",           "Fighter",
     "Ahri",     "Mage,Assassin",
    "Akali",          "Assassin",
   "Akshan", "Marksman,Assassin",
  "Alistar",      "Tank,Support")

# Code (just `separate_rows` and `count` it) ------------------------------
lol_champs <- count(separate_rows(lol_data, tags, sep = ",\\s?"), tags, name = "total_entries")

# Output ------------------------------------------------------------------
lol_champs
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   tags     total_entries
#>   <chr>            <int>
#> 1 Assassin             3
#> 2 Fighter              1
#> 3 Mage                 1
#> 4 Marksman             1
#> 5 Support              1
#> 6 Tank                 1

Created on 2024-07-25 with reprex v2.1.0

You can use scan + table + stack like below
> stack(table(scan(text = df$tags, what = "", sep = ",")))
Read 8 items
  values      ind
1      3 Assassin
2      1  Fighter
3      1     Mage
4      1 Marksman
5      1  Support
6      1     Tank

